# Reset appearance settings for UINavigationBar back to default

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I've been using the fantastic `[[UINavigationBar appearance] set...` to set application wide appearances for my UI. However, I'm using the `SKStoreProductViewController` and want to remove all of my styling so that it shows the default Apple UI. Weirdly, without doing anything, I get a mish mash of normal UI and my custom UI, which I don't really understand. I've tried countering all my UI changes like this:

```
    [storeController.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [storeController.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                           nil, UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                           nil, UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                                           nil]];

    [storeController.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:0 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [storeController.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:0 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

But that doesn't seem to work, making no difference at all. How can I set it back to the default UI settings?

Regards, 
Mike

Comment: Check if `navigationController` already exists when you call your methods.

Comment: also make sure not to work on different navigationBar objects

Comment: @akashivskyy, Ok then guys, here are my findings: `navigationController` doesn't exist... ever. `navigationItem` does exist, but `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` doesn't exist. Weird right?

Comment: Try to call these methods just AFTER `[storeController present...]`. Then the navController should exist.

Comment: @akashivskyy Hmmm, nope, didn't work.

Comment: OK, I will try to test that locally a little bit later (unless you find the solution).

Comment: @akashivskyy Ok then I look forward to hear your findings. Thank you very much for the help. +1.

Comment: Can you show me the code where you assign the global appearance (just to let me see which attributes you change)?

Comment: @akashivskyy Hi again, The stuff I've changed is exactly what I'm trying to reverse in the code above, so `[storeController.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:0 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];` is trying to reverse `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:-6 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`. Hope this helps.

Comment: And what is the result? Which styles stay the same and which are correct (in store view controller)? I have created an example and it seems that only position adjustment is not being reset by SK...ViewController

Comment: You're right, a lot of the time the background is correct, but it stays correct even if you don't right the code to remove it! Then again, sometimes the custom BG can be seen. The positional settings don't reset though, as you stated. For me, leaving out the code in the original post makes no difference at all.

Comment: Bad info: SK...ViewController has no normal view hierarchy. There is no UINavigationBar and no UINavController in there. It's using some private classes (e.g. _UIRemoteView) and after dumping it with lldb, I have not managed to find the navigation bar instance. Seems like a smart move by Apple, so we can't get to the UIWebView and play with the store page.

Comment: @akashivskyy Yea, I thought it wasn't using a NavigationController hierarchy. So why is it inheriting properties for UINavigationBar if it doesn't really have one?

Comment: It may be using the UINavigationBar... somewhere very deep. Maybe you can try to play with `appearanceWhenContainedIn:[SK...ViewController class]`. After viewing the UIKit's and StoreKit's hidden header files I am out of ideas.

Comment: @akashivskyy Well I tried that ages ago and it doesn't work which is annoying. Well thanks for all the help, you've been amazing. I'll keep on persevering and see if I can get anywhere. I'll mark all your comments up so you get the rep you deserve.

Comment: Thanks :) I'll mark this question as favorite, so if I accidentally find the solution in the future, I will post an answer.

Comment: @akashivskyy So I never managed to find out how to change the styling of the `SKStoreProductViewController`, so I had to resort to a nasty workaround. I'm not sure if there will be any unforeseen side effects in doing what I did (check my answer for details) but it works so we'll just have to wait and see.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok then, I've had to resort to a nasty little workaround to fix this issue. While I always knew that this would be one way of doing it, I didn't want to have to resort to it because it feels messy.

I subclassed `UINavigationController` to something like `CustomNavigationViewController` and made absolutely no changes to it. So in other words, it IS `UINavigationController` but with a different name. I then used:

`[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[CustomNavigationViewController class], nil] set....`
to set the appearance, applying it only to those NavigationControllers that are of my custom class. The `SKStoreProductViewController` obviously isn't of my custom class, and therefore doesn't get the styling for it.

This is a nasty, unclean fix in my opinion, but it works.

Mike.

Answer (score 0):

You can be quite specific about styling these items by using the UIAppearance proxy.
THis has a method that applies the styling only when it's contained in a specific view controller class.

There's a good tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21703/user-interface-customization-in-ios-6):

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm afraid this hasn't worked. It was something I tried however. The reason it doesn't work is because the things we are trying to change on the store VC are considered to be in a `navBar`, therefore `appearanceWhenContainedIn` `UINavigationBar` etc, doesn't differentiate it from everything else in the app. On top of that: `Controller.navigatonController.navgiationBar`, apparently doesn't exist so we can't edit the VC there either.